# Run JUnit test programmatically loading different .class files

Tags: java, reflection, junit, classloader, dynamic-class-loaders

i'm currently able to run a JUnit test programmatically doing something like this:

```java
JUnitCore junit = new JUnitCore();
Result result = new Result();

File root = new File("rootWhereSommatoreTest.classIS");
URLClassLoader classLoader = URLClassLoader.newInstance(new URL[]{root.toURI().toURL() });
Class<?> cls = classLoader.loadClass("SommatoreTest");  
result = junit.run(cls);
return result;
```

What i dislike about this code is that SommatoreTest.class must be in the same directory as Sommatore.class to work. So i was wondering if it was possible to run a Junit test, loading separately .class files from different directories in the same ClassLoader, enabling SommatoreTest to "see" Sommatore.

Thanks in advance for your answer! And keep up the good work!

Comment: And just wondering: why exactly do you want that to do? What is the point of loading JUnit tests in such a complicated way?

Comment: I have to make an application in which i have a TestClass loaded on a remote machine and all my students have to write some code and they can run junit test concurrently sending request to this remote machine. (Sorry for bad english) if unclear just tell me. Thanks for your answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You simply need to make sure that the `URL` provided to your `URLClassLoader` matches with the **root folder** of your test class or with the **jar file** that contains your test class.

In your case you seem to use a directory, so assuming that the FQN of your class is `my.package.MyTest` and the file `MyTest.class` is in the directory `/my/class/dir/my/package`, then you need to make sure that the `URL` will match with the root folder of your test class which will be in this case `/my/class/dir/`.

Comment: Thanks for you help @Nicolas Filotto, but i was wondering if i could run `MyTest.class` which is in the directory `/my/class/dir/my/package` using methods from My.class (so the non-TestClass) which is for example located in `my/another/dir/my/package`.  Basically i wanted to know if  `My.class` and `MyTest.class` needs to be necessary in the same directory or maybe there is a workaround to do this?

Comment: No it is not necessary but it is how it is done  by convention/in pratice to be able to access to package private/protected methods/fields/constructors

Comment: Do you think should i use Reflection to achieve my goal?

Comment: I believe that you misundertand something, your class and its related unit test must be in the same **package** which doesn't mean necessary in the same directory. You can put your souces in /foo/src and your test classes in /foo/test such that your class would be in /foo/src/my/package and your test class in /foo/test/my/package. You should consider using maven that splits src and tests out of the box https://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-the-standard-directory-layout.html

Comment: Thanks again Nicolas, as i can see from your comment i need the parent directory to be necessarily the same anyway (foo/).  So there's no way to have MyClass.class (in package MyPackage) on a machine and MyClassTest.class (package MyPackage) on another and getting the things working? I can smell I/O...

Comment: it was just for the example, no they don't need to be in the same parent directory either it could be /some/dir/my/package and /other/random/my/package

Comment: I manged to achieve what i wanted to do! I played a bit with URLs in the ClassLoader definition! Thanks a lot for your help, it was precious!